# Azure App Service - Add Authentication

Tags: web-services, azure

I have an App Service on Azure, and I can easily call this Service thanks to Swagger or SoapUI, but now I would like to secure my App Service by using a Login/Password or any other solutions.
I have tried to do it with Active Directory but I'm not sure it's the best solution (and it doesn't work for me :D).

Can you help me ? ^^. How can I secure it ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Regards,

Comment: what options did you try.? did you already check posts on docs on this topic ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview?toc=%2fazure%2fapp-service-api%2ftoc.json if you have any issue with particular code piece please do post the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an article how to enable that users need to authentication using Azure Active Directory [here](http://www.basiccloud.eu/uncategorized/integrate-azure-active-directory-authentication-to-your-website/). Skip to the section *Active Directory Configuration*.
Should not be that difficult.

The beginning of the article is about reading Active Directory using the Graph API, that is not applicable for your config.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful and well detailed. It seems to work :D

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look on Azure Easy Auth. I believe that it's the easiest way to achieve that:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-websites-easy-authentication-and-authorization-with-chris-gillum/

Comment: Thanks for the link, it helps me to understand some things on authorizatino :D !!